# Как задать блоку высоту body?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как задать блоку `.block` высоту, равную высоте всего контента(`body`)?
Высота всего контента не известа, возможно ли это как-то сделать без js?
Я могу сделать `position: fixed` для `.block` и высоту 100% или 100vh и будет почти тот же эффект, но мне интересно, есть ли такое свойство/хак вообще

```css
.block {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

.block__1 {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.block__2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class=".container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block__1"></div>
    <div class="block__2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: не делать блок абсолютным?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, это то что вам нужно?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.block__1 {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.block__2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block__1">
    </div>
    <div class="block__2">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```